# LibreOffice Spreadsheet: Select random cell with specific filter

Tags: select, random, filter, spreadsheet, libreoffice

Helo.

I have the following scenario on LibreOffice Spreadsheet

- In one table I have entries with specific state

e.g:

```
id   state     name
----------------------------
1    open      OpenState
2    closed    ClosedState
3    resolved  ResolvedState
...
```

- In the other table I have list of projects that have *random* State-ID from the first table. That works fine.

e.g:

```
id   state   ProjectName
------------------------
1    1       Proj_1
2    1       Proj_2
3    2       Proj_3
...
```

- I have problems with the third table. In this table I want generate test data. The entries have also the state from the first table. Now I need a LibreOffice function to assign each entry a **random** project from the second table that have the **same** state as the entry state

e.g.:

```
id   state   project   EntryName
--------------------------------
1    1       2         Entry_1
2    1       1         Entry_2
3    1       1         Entry_3
4    2       3         Entry_4
...
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO this task exceeds calc's possibilities. The main problem is that there seems to be no formula that returns a subset of rows (the projects sharing the same state). This would require filtering, but there seems to be no way to apply filtering on-the-fly. So, this won't work without preparing the second table holding each project's state.

So, IMO the easiest solution would be to create three persistent filter results, listing the projects with identical state. With those filter results, you could use the functions `INDEX` and `RANDBETWEEN` to select one of the project ids randomly.

Filtering the projects may lead to this sheet:

[image: Projects]

With each of the three filter results defined as named ranges (`ProjState1`: `$E$1:$G$4` etc.), you could use the following formula:

```
=IF(($B2=1);INDEX(ProjState1;RANDBETWEEN(2;ROWS(ProjState1));1) ;IF(($B2=2);INDEX(ProjState2;RANDBETWEEN(2;ROWS(ProjState2));1);INDEX(ProjState3;RANDBETWEEN(2;ROWS(ProjState3));1)))
```

RANDBETWEEN returns a random number between two integers; the first is 2 (because i've included the headers as row 1 of the ranges), the second is the last row of the range). INDEX selects the value of the randomly returned row.

Split up on multiple lines:

```
=IF(
    ($B2=1);
    INDEX(
        ProjState1;
        RANDBETWEEN(
            2;
            ROWS(ProjState1)
        );
        1
    );
    IF(
        ($B2=2);
        INDEX(ProjState2;RANDBETWEEN(2;ROWS(ProjState2));1);
        INDEX(ProjState3;RANDBETWEEN(2;ROWS(ProjState3));1)
    )
)
```

with this "entries" table:

[image: Entries]